# Facebook AppRequests: Send request to users of iOS only

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

The latest Facebook iOS SDK (3.2) includes native methods for sending AppRequests to a user's friends via the FBWebDialogs class.  Does it have any way to filter the recipients' list to friends that use iOS devices?  Does Facebook keep any sort of database with these relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - you can add 'devices' to the 'fields' parameter when querying the user's friends, create your own custom friend picker for app requests which parses users based on their devices, and send the list you build as a parameter to apprequests.